# How to integrate opencv code in django framework

Tags: django, opencv3.0

I am making openCV base face recognition project... now I want to ( face recognition) project deploy to django framework

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pickle

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascades/data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascades/data/haarcascade_eye.xml')
smile_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascades/data/haarcascade_smile.xml')


recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
recognizer.read("./recognizers/face-trainner.yml")
```

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: How to integrate opencv code in django framework